# Create large instance from my micro instance (AWS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have a micro instance with Ubuntu 11.10 as the OS.
I would like to create a Large/Small instance based on my micro instance.

Is that OK to create an image from the micro instance and to use it to launch the Large/Small
instances?

And will it be OK to create the image while the instance is still running?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that OK to create an image from the micro instance and to use it to launch the Large/Small instances?

Yes It's alright. We do it. Servers running for years. No problem. (:

> And will it be OK to create the image while the instance is still running?

Yes. I always take caution to stop processes, delete unrequired, temp files, log files just to avoid these stuffs go into image. But anyways, it does not matter a-lot. Your system will halt/reboot once, I guess, while creating the AMI.